# How to loop through complex json object

Tags: arrays, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am receiving complex JSON object from server side. I have no idea how to loop through such an object. Here's the object.

```
"message": {
        "name": ["Name cannot be blank."],
        "contact_person": ["Contact Person cannot be blank."],
        "username": ["Username cannot be blank."]
    },
```

I am using `angularjs` and using `ng-repeat` to iterate through.

```
<div style="color: red;" ng-repeat="err in message">{{err}}</div>
```

where message is. `$scope.message=justdata.message`
and this is what I get:
[image]

How can I format it in proper way. Please help me out!

Comment: Have you tried {{err.name[0]}} and so on.

Comment: Could you show a little more of your json and what do you want to archieve?

Comment: Since your error messages are in an array loop through key/value of the message object and print value[0]: `<div style="color: red;" ng-repeat="(key, value) in message">{{value[0]}}</div>`

Comment: @SudhirOjha , yep not working

Comment: @Kavindra, that seems to be working with {{value[$index]}} also. I'll test more possibilities. THanks

Comment: @Steve If you have more than one element in those arrays, you need to loop through the value again in another ng-repeat inside that div. e.g.: `<span ng-repeat="msg in value">{{msg}}<span>`

Answer (score 1):

This is working fine for me you need to have nested ng-repeat inside div because you error message is coming in list. You have to again loop through it. Like following:

```
 <div style="color: red;" ng-repeat="err in message">
      <span ng-repeat="val in err">
        {{val}}
      </span>
    </div>
```

Here is working code

```html
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<div style="color: red;" ng-repeat="err in message">
  <span ng-repeat="val in err">
    {{val}}
  </span>
</div>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.message =  {
        "name": ["Name cannot be blank."],
        "contact_person": ["Contact Person cannot be blank."],
        "username": ["Username cannot be blank."]
    };
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that you seemingly want to output a list of error messages, I would pre-process `$scope.message` to just be an array of strings. Something like this should do the trick:

```
var payload = {
  "message": {
    "name": ["Name cannot be blank."],
    "contact_person": ["Contact Person cannot be blank."],
    "username": ["Username cannot be blank."]
  }
};

$scope.errors = [].concat.apply([], Object.values(payload.message));
```

This will populate `$scope.errors` with an array of error messages, that you can then iterate through using `ng-repeat`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
<div style="color: red;" ng-repeat="err in message">{{err[0]}}</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain, what's the use of `[0]`?

Comment: its type is Array and its length is 1 so you can access its value on 0 index.